# Setting spring active profiles in amazon AWS EC2 instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup Amazon AWS EC2 instance and have installed tomcat8 and jdk 1.8.
I have deployed Spring/Hibernate based web-app war file in my tomcat's webapps directory and so far everything works fine. Its Spring Web MVC.

But I want to implement **spring.active.profiles** with my existing configuration which never works.

Below is my JPAConfig file's content which works well on local server but just not on **AWS EC2**. I feel there's some misconfiguration on my EC2 instance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({ 
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),

       @PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:api.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:mailer.properties") })
    public class JPAConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

    //rest or codes
```

**If I comment `@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"),` line then things work fine on EC2 but it picks up `application.properties` file contents for obvious reasons. And when I uncomment it, my EC2 URL returns 404 NOT found.**

Please help in implementing spring.active.profiles feature on EC2 instance so that my EC2 instance uses my `application-prod.properties` file

Also, **please note that for some unknown reason, I cant see any other directory except "webapps" in my tomcat8's directory**

Comment: I assume you are using plain spring, and not spring boot, as you didn't mention it.
How are you setting the `spring.profiles.active` property?

Comment: Spring web-mvc am using

Comment: On my local server, using maven and this configuration `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <path>/dms-web</path>
     <port>9400</port>
     <systemProperties>
      <spring.profiles.active>local</spring.profiles.active>
     </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>`

Comment: That example doesn't mention anything  related to amazon EC2

Comment: never used it, but I guess this plugin starts tomcat or however configures it to serve your webapp on a certain path and port, passing a system property to the spawned jvm. on ec2 you are not using it hence the active profile property is not set

Comment: Amazon EC2 gives you virtual instances with OS, then you install some software on them. What kind of EC2-specific stuff do you expect? IMHO your issue is not specific to EC2. BTW: how did you get tomcat up and running on EC2? Did you use an AMI with tomcat installed?

Comment: My issue is specific to EC2 because I just am unable to figure out how to configure EC2 to use environment specific properties. Its working perfect on local server as mentioned in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Set the active profile(s) on an artifact deployed within EC2 instance, i.e.
on the web.xml packaged within the war:

`web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or using annotations, etc. see
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/
If your tomcat is serving only this application (or `prod` ones you can also pass `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` to the jvm, i.e. from `CATALINA_OPTS` env var I guess.

If your webapp is the only one hosted on that tomcat please also consider using Spring Boot and package the webapp as a fat jar.